# Is there a way to use the 'is' type check operator with RandomAccessCollection?

Tags: swift, protocols

I'm getting the following error on the 'if' condition:

*"Protocol 'RandomAccessCollection' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements"*

```
let str = "mystring"

let v = str.utf8

if v is RandomAccessCollection {
    print("YES")
} else {
    print("NO")
}
```

**Out of curiosity, is there a way to use the "is" type check operator to check if an object/instance conforms to RandomAccessCollection?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These type checks at **runtime** are *unswifty*. Don't do that.

A possible way is method overloading, the check is performed at **compile time** for example

```
func checkType<T>(obj: T) {
    print("NO")
}

func checkType<T:RandomAccessCollection>(obj: T) {
    print("YES")
}

let str = "mystring"
let v = str.utf8
checkType(obj: v) // prints NO

let x = Data(v)
checkType(obj: x)  // prints YES
```

If the object conforms to the protocol the second method is called otherwise the first.

Comment: Okay. Out of curiosity, is there a way to do it w/ the "is" keyword?

Comment: I don't think so. As the error says a protocol which *has Self or associated type requirements* – which `RandomAccessCollection` has  – *can only be used as a generic constraint*